# Notify user we would like them to clear their cookie. Provide a working button to clear cookies for user

Tags: jquery, javascript, woocommerce-offtopic, cookies

**Explination:**

We are facing some issues with logged in users being able to checkout via wordpress's woocommerce. The fix for these few users that reached out to us was to simply clear their cookies. (Because we recently changed servers which mucked things up a bit causing this checkout issue)

So i want to provide a red bar at the top of our checkout and cart pages that recommends to our users that they update the cookies to our site. And provide a button they can click that will remove the cookie for them.

---

**Problem:**

Okay so i have this script.. Which I am told is suppose to work.

```
<a href="#" class="clearAllCookies">Start your bacon</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clearAllCookies").click(function() {
        deleteAllCookies();
        document.location = "start.html";
    });
});
```

However when i open dev tools and select the application tab. *I am able* to clear my cookie by simply right clicking and selecting clear - at which point it deletes itself and removes itself from the cookie folder.

But when I am in dev tools and use this button script to clear my cookie. The cookie remains in the file unlike if i cleared it manually by right clicking on it in dev tools. So I am unsure if its working or not. How do i properly test this?

---

Also how do i make it re-direct the user to the login page afterwards?

Any help much appreciated. Not sure if its working.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check [if a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092218/check-if-cookie-exists-else-set-cookie-to-expire-in-10-days) of your website is set in the user's browser. If so, display a message.

If you'd like to delete all his cookies [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595228/how-can-i-delete-all-cookies-with-javascript).

Comment: Thanks! But how do i apply that script you linked to a button click? Can u give an example of that in your answer?

Many thanks!